# How to optimize the `explain select` kind of query results in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask about certain kind of query in Apache IoTDB. When I try to execute `explain select ReportLoopType, PriorityLevel, CasStatisticsType from root.pideval_loop_cycle where ProjectID = 3277489752686800 and (time = 1700539200000) order by time desc align by device` query, the result has no data, but it takes six or seven seconds to finish this execution. I want to know are there anything that I can do to optimize this exectuin speed?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `explain` query of Apache IoTDB is slow is generally because there are many devices being queried. If you want to improve this efficiency, you can specify several precise devices after `from` in your query statement. If you refer to why the `select` query is slow, you can upgrade to the latest 1.3.0 version of IoTDB and try again. This kind of query has been specifically optimized in the latest version.